# Trying to query AD users, but getting less than expected results

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to query AD to get the list of users
The query is success, and I am getting 90 records as results, the problem is that I am expecting more over than 15000 records.

Before I go to the IT and check the right domain path, it would be great if I am sure that my code is not the issue.

Thank you for every much

Already tried changing the search page size

```
DataTable resultSet = new DataTable();
resultSet.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mail", typeof (string)));
resultSet.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("username", typeof (string)));
resultSet.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("displayname", typeof (string)));
try
{
    string DomainPath = "LDAP://MyDomain";
    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath);
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");                
    search.PageSize = 1001;
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");//first name
    SearchResult result;
    SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
    if (resultCol != null)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
        {
            result = resultCol[counter];
            if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") && result.Properties.Contains("mail") && result.Properties.Contains("displayname"))
            {
                var row = resultSet.NewRow();
                resultSet.Rows.Add(row);
                var Email = (String) result.Properties["mail"][0];
                row["mail"] = Email;
                var UserName = (String) result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
                row["username"] = UserName;
                var DisplayName = (String) result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                row["displayname"] = DisplayName;
                row.AcceptChanges();

            }

        }
        resultCol.Dispose();

    }

} 

catch (Exception ex)
{
    App.Log.Write("Exception while read user from AD: " + ex.ToString());

}
return resultSet;
```

Expected over 15000 records getting 90 only

Comment: a) I wonder if your edited domainpath is fine. Its usually something like `LDAP://ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com`. b) Your filter should filter for those containing mail and displayname, should be `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(displayname=*)(mail=*))` that way you will query what you want to query.

Comment: I have delete the LDAP path since it's a customer's domain name, the domain name is ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=local, I changed the filter as you suggested but getting the same results

Comment: Your code seems right. From personal experience I have seen poor AD data (try removing objectCategory and/or objectClass) because sometimes the data is not as it was expected to be.

Comment: I have queried the root folder instead of a specific OU and got 8000 records as a result. I think the code is right, and as you mentioned I think the AD is poorly managed, Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you expecting 15000 records? Where did you get that number from?

Comment: From the customer's IT at least 15000 I am expecting.